# how to check if an external folder is mounted

Tags: server, mount

I had a linux server where run my application, in this application an user can storage file in another server.

When the server start mount the link with the folder on storage server, For some time it's all ok.
But now, almoust every day I have to restart the server because the link is lost.

Have you have a suggestion for check if the folder is mount and (in case isn't) mount it? And why now lost the mount, I don't understand it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's the mount method you use?
me, I have declared a webdav server in /etc/fstab, so for checking if it's mounted I have to read /etc/mtab

(some documentation here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mtab)

in a script it could be like this, (my server is called owncloud):

```
#!/bin/bash
ismounted=$(cat /etc/mtab | grep owncloud )
if [ -z "${ismounted}" ]; then
    echo "not mounted!!" 
    mount "owncloud"
else

    echo "server mounted!"
fi
```

what I do is check if I found some entry about my server in mtab, and if it's entry is empty simply mount it. (I've added the echo commands for more info)

You can execute this script automatically every x minutes/Seconds, etc. or at startup using a daemon, as cronnie.

I've found other people who use differents methods as seen here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38870/how-to-check-if-a-filesystem-is-mounted-with-a-script

hope it helps.
cheers!

Comment: Thank you, i will try to do.  In /etc/fstab and in  /etc/mtab I see the mount, but in the app the request go to time out in randomic time.

Comment: and it's solved remounting?

Comment: I have to wait for a recurrence of the problem. It's randomic, It might work until tomorrow, or for 10 minutes.

Comment: PaolaG could you edit your post adding the error code and info? Sure it's useful

Comment: I don't have error code. Now It's blocked, but the mount is up.  But the problem is the communication with the storage server.

Comment: well, perhaps we can play a bit with the fstab mounting options. Which type of connection you have between servers? (have you got any other methods to test connection? as ping, http , etc.? to test we have connection but not a working mounting point)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31042/discussion-between-gentooza-and-paolag).